# TSQL Extracting Numbers between backslashes

Tags: t-sql, numbers, extract, between, backslash

I am trying to extract the first lot of digits that appear in the same place but can vary in length. I have tried SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, PATINDEX, REVERSE in different ways but I can't crack it.

Here is the format of the strings

\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf

\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\141590\Contract\141590.pdf

So the result from those two would be 
13030
141590

Comment: I think better way is use CLR function with Regex

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Cast Method?

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf','\','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[5]','int');
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\141590\Contract\141590.pdf','\','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[5]','int');
```

Check Live at this [snippet](http://rextester.com/EAWNO75874)

Answer (score 0):

Considering with `appear in the same place`:

```
declare @temp table (val varchar(250));

insert @temp values
('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf'),
('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\141590\Contract\141590.pdf');

declare @start int = 51;

select substring(val, @start, charindex('\', val, @start) - @start) num
    from @temp;
```

Output:

```
num
------
13030
141590
```

Is this code ok for you?

Comment: Why are you declaring `@start` to 51 when the length of string can vary as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(4000) = N'\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf'


-- 12743.pdf
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@value), 0, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@value))))      

-- 12743
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@value), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@value)), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@value)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@value))))
```

If you are always working with `.pdf` or some set of extensions you can use the first variant and replace the extension. If you need to do this on the fly, we need to get the first number in order to use it as a start index in the `SUBSTRING` function.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a really fast T-SQL function for exactly this kind of thing using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

**The Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K
(
  @string    varchar(8000),
  @start     tinyint,
  @stop      tinyint,
  @delimiter char(1)
)
/*****************************************************************************************
Purpose:
 Takes in input string (@string) and returns the text between two instances of a delimiter
 (@delimiter); the location of the delimiters is defined by @start and @stop.
 For example: if @string = 'xx.yy.zz.abc', @start=1, @stop=3, and @delimiter = '.' the
 function will return the text: yy.zz; this is the text between the first and third
 instance of "." in the string "xx.yy.zz.abc".

Compatibility:
 SQL Server 2008+

Syntax:
--===== Autonomous use
 SELECT sb.token, sb.position, sb.tokenLength
 FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string, @start, @stop, @delimiter); sb;

--===== Use against a table
 SELECT sb.token, sb.position, sb.tokenLength
 FROM SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(st.SomeColumn1, 1, 2, '.') sb;

Parameters:
 @string    = varchar(8000); Input string to parse
 @start     = tinyint; the instance of @delimiter to search for; this is where the output 
              should start. When @start is 0 then the function will return everything from
              the beginning of @string until @end.
 @stop      = tinyint; the last instance of @delimiter to search for; this is where the
              output should end. When @end is 0 then the function will return everything
              from @start until the end of the string.
 @delimiter = char(1); this is the delimiter use to determine where the output starts/ends

Return Types:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
   token     = varchar(8000); the substring between the two instances of @delimiter 
               defined by @start and @stop
 position    = smallint; the location of where the substring begins
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Developer Notes:
 1. Requires NGrams8K. The code for NGrams8K can be found here:
    http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/

 2. This function is what is referred to as an "inline" scalar UDF." Technically it's an
    inline table valued function (iTVF) but performs the same task as a scalar valued user
    defined function (UDF); the difference is that it requires the APPLY table operator
    to accept column values as a parameter. For more about "inline" scalar UDFs see this
    article by SQL MVP Jeff Moden: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/
    and for more about how to use APPLY see the this article by SQL MVP Paul White:
    http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/.

    Note the above syntax example and usage examples below to better understand how to
    use the function. Although the function is slightly more complicated to use than a
    scalar UDF it will yield notably better performance for many reasons. For example,
    unlike a scalar UDFs or multi-line table valued functions, the inline scalar UDF does
    not restrict the query optimizer's ability generate a parallel query execution plan.

 3. dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K is deterministic; for more about deterministic and
    nondeterministic functions see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx

Examples:
-- beginning of string to 2nd delimiter, 2nd delimiter to end of the string
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'abc.defg.hi.jk.lmnop.qrs.tuv';
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,0,2, '.');
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,2,0, '.');

-- Between the 1st & 2nd, then 2nd & 5th delimiters
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,1,2, '.');
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,2,5, '.');

-- dealing with NULLS, delimiters that don't exist and when @first = @last
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,2,10,'.');
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,1,NULL,'.');
SELECT string=@string, token, position FROM dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(@string,NULL,1,'.');
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 20160720 - Initial Creation - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20160821 - Re-wrote a single-char version (this); removed tokenLen
****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH
chars AS
(
 SELECT instance = 0, position = 0 WHERE @start = 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position), position
 FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@string,1)
 WHERE token = @delimiter
 UNION ALL
 SELECT -1, DATALENGTH(@string)+1 WHERE @stop = 0
)
SELECT 
  token = SUBSTRING
          (
            @string,
            MIN(position)+1,
            NULLIF(MAX(position),MIN(position)) - MIN(position)-1
          ),
  position = CAST
            (
            CASE WHEN NULLIF(MAX(position),MIN(position)) - MIN(position)-1 > 0
            THEN MIN(position)+1 END AS smallint
          )
FROM chars
WHERE instance IN (@start, NULLIF(@stop,0), -1);
GO
```

Example using your data:

```
declare @sometable table (someid int identity, someString varchar(1000));
insert @sometable(someString) values
('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf'),
('\zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\141590\Contract\141590.pdf');

select *
from @sometable s
cross apply dbo.SubstringBetweenChar8K(s.someString, 4, 5, '\');
```

Results:

```
someid      someString                                                                          token   position
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------- --------
1           \zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\13030\12743\Contract\12743.pdf    13030   51
2           \zfilemgr3-00\Corporate\On the Market Information\141590\Contract\141590.pdf        141590  51
```